# How to change size of luminosity trackbar in CHOOSECOLOR Dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, colordialog, common-dialog

I'm using the CHOOSECOLOR dialog, but in my app(C++/WinAPI) it looks wierd. Dialog has large luminosity slider and I do not why. I haven't found a way to make the slider smaller.

[a busy cat http://toxicbumble.com/color_dialog.png](http://toxicbumble.com/color_dialog.png)

Dialog is created by this code (it's example code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#choosing_color)):

```
CHOOSECOLOR cc;                 // common dialog box structure 
static COLORREF acrCustClr[16]; // array of custom colors 
HWND hwnd;                      // owner window
HBRUSH hbrush;                  // brush handle
static DWORD rgbCurrent;        // initial color selection

// Initialize CHOOSECOLOR 
ZeroMemory(&cc, sizeof(cc));
cc.lStructSize = sizeof(cc);
cc.hwndOwner = hwnd;
cc.lpCustColors = (LPDWORD) acrCustClr;
cc.rgbResult = rgbCurrent;
cc.Flags = CC_FULLOPEN | CC_RGBINIT;

ChooseColor(&cc);
```

Comment: You're right, your slider does look too big, I compared it to mspaint's color chooser on my computer. How does mspaint's color chooser dialog look like on your computer? If it has a big slider as well, it might be something with the Windows theme you have on that computer, rather than a problem with your code.

Comment: Color dialog in MS Paint on my computer is ok. [screenshot](http://toxicbumble.com/color_dialog_mspaint.png)

Comment: I ran your code in a new project on my computer, but couldn't reproduce the problem. I modified it a bit, can you try running it in a new project on your computer? http://pastebin.com/reKbhDzC

Comment: I tried your sample in new project and color dialog looks perfect. I must try to move my whole application to a new project.